# How to automatically insert data in mongoose js at certain time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

As I am building website using node js and mongoose i need one hint of help that how i can automatically insert data in mongoose node js at certain time. Example at end of every month my data current data should automatically be stored in mongoose data base.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node-cron to perform any CRON operation in node js.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Example:

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

/* CRON JOB Scheduled to daily at 12AM */
cron.schedule('0 0 12 1/1 * ? *', () => {
  // Add your API/Logic here to insert data in mongoose using node.js
});
```

[CRON generator](http://www.cronmaker.com/)